# Why data in Windows is erasing on booting?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am using windows7 ultimate. In my computer,whenever I shutdown the system the data saved (suppose in Downloads folder) is getting erased. I have checked in users folder that whether I am entering into another account but it's not the case. I have changed password for that account also(it has admin privileges). Also I installed some software but they are present. 
And in the chrome browser, whenever I open it after booting I have to set the Lan settings again and again (as we are using manual proxy to access the internet). And one more thing , on the log in screen after I enter the password usually It has to show "Welcome" and our desktop will be shown but here every time "Welcome" along with "Preparing your desktop" is showing. 
What to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a folder in c:\ and reboot. Does this persist? If so I would suspect that Windows is using a temporary profile which would cause this exact problem. Try creating a second user and log in using that account. Do you get the same problems?

Comment: what is the purpose of creating  "c:\" folder? What actually it does?

Comment: Actually I mean a folder in c:\ like "c:\test" The reason I am suggesting this is to see if all changes on the filesystem get reverted on a reboot or just the changes inside the user profile.

Comment: Thank you. I have created a folder in "c:\" and it was not erased. Later as you said I created another account and my problem of erasing data is solved. I want to ask you one thing that what is temporary profile in Windows. How it will effect the data. ?

Comment: every user on a windows system gets a user profile directory. This directory houses your desktop, documents, downloads, etc. Also the user portion of the windows registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) is stored here. In some cases something can go wrong with this profile directory. If Windows can't use the stored profile directory it sometimes starts using a temporary profile when logging on. This temporary profile gets deleted when logging off again (or turning off the computer.)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using some kind of sandboxing software like Shadow Defender (www.shadowdefender.com)? Look at the list here: https://alternativeto.net/software/shadow-defender/ . If you have some software from the list it could be reason.